# Getting error when i call api " Access-Control-Allow-Origin"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Failed to load http://look_at_me.api.co/api/contact: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://test.com' is therefore not allowed access.

local Url => http://test.com
api url => http://look_at_me.api.co/api/contact

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure your API service has cross domain feature.